# Is this "accidental unitarity" of the Poisson PMF significant?

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, soft-question

A Poisson distribution is one with a PMF of the form $\exp(-\lambda)\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$ for some $\lambda>0$, its support the set $\Bbb Z^\ast$ of non-negative integers. In particular, $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\exp(-\lambda)\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}=1$ regardless of $\lambda$. The probabilities sum to $1$, of course; that's what we call unitarity. I'll use the term "accidental unitarity" for the superficially similar-looking result $\int_0^\infty\exp(-\lambda)\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}d\lambda=1$, regardless of $k$ (in fact, it works for any *real* $k\ge0$).

There are distributions that are "nearly accidentally unitary", if you pick the right integration range. For example, the Poisson distribution is obtained via $n\to\infty$ from $B\left(n,\,\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)$, so it makes sense to look at something that happens with Binomial distributions:

$$\int_{0}^{n}\frac{\Gamma\left(n+1\right)}{\Gamma\left(k+1\right)\Gamma\left(n-k+1\right)}\left(\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^{k}\left(1-\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^{n-k}d\lambda=\frac{n}{n+1}$$(a trivial exercise in Beta functions), again regardless of $k$.

But I doubt we can write a similar result in general. For example, the [logarithmic distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_distribution) relies on the identity $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{-1}{\ln(1-p)}\frac{p^k}{k}=1$ for any $p\in(0,\,1)$, but $\int_0^1\frac{-1}{\ln(1-p)}\frac{p^k}{k}dp$ depends on $k$ in quite a complicated way (which I've still not fully ascertained; but based on small $k$, for any $k\in\Bbb N$ it seems to be a rational combination of the logarithms of finitely many positive integers).

Is what happens with the Normal and Poisson distributions as meaningless in isolation as the [sophomore's dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream), or is there more to it? For example, can we identify a sufficient but not particularly stringent condition for a one-parameter family of PMFs $f(\lambda,\,k)$ viz. $\sum_{k\in S}f(\lambda,\,k)=1$ with the same support $S$ to yield a $k$-independent integral $\int_{S^\prime}f(\lambda,\,k)\lambda$, ideally equal to $1$? (Or to mirror the binomial case, $\sum_{k\in S_n}f_n(\lambda,\,k)=1,\,\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{S_n^\prime}f_n(\lambda,\,k)\lambda=1$.)

I suspect my decisions on how to tag this question could do with some work, so feel free to edit those.